# Class method "call" and return value: how to get it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm completely new to ruby / ruby on rails, i'm just giving a sort of extreme assistance on an old existing project, so, forgive myself if this is a silly question ;)

I have this class:

```
class MyClass
  def call
    category_id = context.params['category_id']
    tmp_context = context.clone

    ... stuff...

    content_id
  end
end
```

Called this way:

```
MyClass.call(params: params, current_user: current_user)
```

All i need to get is the return value of the function, the "content_id".
I've tried in several ways and all i can get from this function it's a reference to the context:

```
#<Interactor::Context params={...}, current_user=#<User ...>>
```

But no hint about the return value.

Any suggestion?

Comment: how you call the method (with arguments) doesn't line up with the class you provided.  I assume `#call` is returning early and not the last value?  We probably need the whole method to help you debug

Comment: I think this is just called in action's controller and so it uses this default current_user and params (from the action). What it's strange to me, that's not a class method. Unless there is something we can't see.

Comment: The class you have provided declares `call` as an instance method. This should give `NoMethodError: undefined method 'call' for MyClass:Class`.

Comment: It doesn't raise any error. This is code that i've found on the project, and it works.
This is the full code:
https://gist.github.com/angelicarosa-spindox/b3d8ac508aa9f5c25b5db06be76ae639#file-upload_content_to_thron-rb-L37

Comment: Then the Interactor module must be declaring a `call` class method. Because `def foo` in a Ruby class declares an instance method and `def self.foo` would declare a class method. Thats some pretty basic irrefutable facts.

Comment: Why doesn't it raise an error? Could anyone tell me please. I thought it wouldn't work without an object, i.e. unless it's `MyClass.new.call`.

Comment: there is another module there that must be defining `self.call`

Comment: You can use `MyClass.method(:call).source_location` to track it down.

Comment: Thank you @max, It's inside a gem: ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/interactor-3.1.0/lib/interactor.rb

Comment: @Anthony I see, thank you. @AngelicaRosa, I think line *32* returns `Interactor::Context` before `content_id` could be returned. As far as I understand that means that either line *7* or *20* is returning `Interactor::Context`.

Comment: My case is the other one, line #35 (category is not an array)

Comment: I've also tried to add a context.content_id = 'foo' at the beginning of the "call" method, but when i debug the result context, content_id is not there.

Comment: And then... i restarted the app, and it worked. Thank you all!

Answer (score 4):

> The call class method is the proper way to invoke an interactor. The
>   hash argument is converted to the interactor instance's context. The
>   call instance method is invoked along with any hooks that the
>   interactor might define. Finally, the context (along with any changes
>   made to it) is returned.
>   https://github.com/collectiveidea/interactor

So the proper way to assign a "return value" would be:

```
class MyClass
  include Interactor

  def call
    category_id = context.params['category_id']
    tmp_context = context.clone

    # ...

    context.content_id = content_id
  end
end

MyClass.call.content_id # => some value
```

So to break this down the Interactor module (provided by the interactor gem). Declares a class method named `call` which creates an instance of MyClass with the "context" as an argument. It then calls the `call` instance method on the instance and returns the context.

You can get a better idea of how this works by looking at the [source code](https://github.com/collectiveidea/interactor/blob/7fb2c041b516bf71bdb03715dbabe44c2f83cd47/lib/interactor.rb).